# Error: The argument type 'void Function(ImageInfo, bool)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'ImageStreamListener'

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

After upgrading flutter run, the app doesn't run. I upgrade because `ImageStreamListener`

I tried to change around different channels [master, stable, dev] and not work.

I found [this](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/33827) issue in Flutter but its not helpful.

Here is my `flutter doctor`

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel unknown, v1.7.11, on Mac OS X 10.14.5 18F132, locale en-PE)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 10.2.1)
[✓] iOS tools - develop for iOS devices
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.4)
[!] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2019.1)
    ✗ Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    ✗ Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
[✓] VS Code (version 1.36.0)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)
```

And the error message

```
Compiler message:                                                       
file:///Users/enzoftware/Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/palette_generator-0.1.1/lib/palette_generator.dart:188:29: Error: The argument type 'void Function(ImageInfo, bool)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'ImageStreamListener'.
 - 'ImageInfo' is from 'package:flutter/src/painting/image_stream.dart' ('file:///Users/enzoftware/Development/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/image_stream.dart').
 - 'ImageStreamListener' is from 'package:flutter/src/painting/image_stream.dart' ('file:///Users/enzoftware/Development/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/image_stream.dart').
Try changing the type of the parameter, or casting the argument to 'ImageStreamListener'.
      stream.removeListener(imageListener);                             
                            ^                                           
file:///Users/enzoftware/Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/palette_generator-0.1.1/lib/palette_generator.dart:194:31: Error: The argument type 'void Function(ImageInfo, bool)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'ImageStreamListener'.
 - 'ImageInfo' is from 'package:flutter/src/painting/image_stream.dart' ('file:///Users/enzoftware/Development/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/image_stream.dart').
 - 'ImageStreamListener' is from 'package:flutter/src/painting/image_stream.dart' ('file:///Users/enzoftware/Development/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/image_stream.dart').
Try changing the type of the parameter, or casting the argument to 'ImageStreamListener'.
        stream.removeListener(imageListener);                           
                              ^                                         
file:///Users/enzoftware/Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/palette_generator-0.1.1/lib/palette_generator.dart:201:24: Error: The argument type 'void Function(ImageInfo, bool)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'ImageStreamListener'.
 - 'ImageInfo' is from 'package:flutter/src/painting/image_stream.dart' ('file:///Users/enzoftware/Development/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/image_stream.dart').
 - 'ImageStreamListener' is from 'package:flutter/src/painting/image_stream.dart' ('file:///Users/enzoftware/Development/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/image_stream.dart').
Try changing the type of the parameter, or casting the argument to 'ImageStreamListener'.
    stream.addListener(imageListener);                                  
                       ^                                                
Compiler failed on /Users/enzoftware/Projects/Wibo/wibo-flutter-mobile-user/lib/main.dart

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.                                

* Where:                                                                
Script '/Users/enzoftware/Development/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle' line: 652

* What went wrong:                                                      
Execution failed for task ':app:compileflutterBuildDebugArm'.           
> Process 'command '/Users/enzoftware/Development/flutter/bin/flutter'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:                                                                  
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org                              

BUILD FAILED in 29s                                                     
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                                  
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                        29.7s
Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That API had a recent breaking change.

here's an example of old vs new use

```
    // get the width, height
    Image image = new Image.file(myImageFile);
    Completer<ImageInfo> completer = Completer();

    // Old API
//    image.image
//        .resolve(new ImageConfiguration())
//        .addListener((ImageInfo info, bool _) {
//      completer.complete(info);
//    });

    // New API
    image.image
        .resolve(new ImageConfiguration())
        .addListener(ImageStreamListener((ImageInfo info, bool _) {
      completer.complete(info);
    }));

    // wait for ImageInfo to finish
    ImageInfo imageInfo = await completer.future;
```

Comment: @Daibaku, looks like version 0.2.0 (vs 0.1.1 in the question) of the palette_generator plugin was published on July 19, 2019. So this is likely updated to the new API.

Comment: thank you for comment aaron. actually I face this issue after I upgraded sdk to newest one. what should I do?

Comment: @aaronvargas Where i need to apply those changes?  because in my source i never find that old code.

Comment: @HirenVaghela, it's likely that a library you're using needs to be updated. In the OP it was the palette_generator-0.1.1 that needed to be updated to 0.2.0

Answer (score 6):

I struggled with this for a couple of days and then, as an experiment, copied the source code from zoomable_image and created a local file zoomable.dart and edited the offending lines:

```
_imageStream.addListener(_handleImageLoaded);
_imageStream.removeListener(_handleImageLoaded);
```

to

```
_imageStream.addListener(ImageStreamListener(_handleImageLoaded));
_imageStream.removeListener(ImageStreamListener(_handleImageLoaded));
```

I don't feel competent to check out the git file and fix it being a newbie to git. Shouldn't the owner do this?

Answer (score 0):

I got solution from below link :

https://github.com/renefloor/flutter_cached_network_image/issues/197

```
this._networkImage.image.resolve(ImageConfiguration()).addListener(
            ImageStreamListener((ImageInfo image, bool synchronousCall) {
          if (mounted)
            setState(() => this._imageDownloadState = ImageDownloadState.Done);
        }));
```

And who are using firebase_storage_image.dart file, mostly this issue will come. Above code will work for that.

https://gist.github.com/jeroen-meijer/f0996dd35065c17ac79eeb3938bc89e4